# Protractor - can I use url params to set localstorage?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor

In my app, I used to change one variable to change to test mode.

Now, I changed that a bit so that I can add an URL param (`test=true`) to set my app to run with the mocked backend and all the stuff required when testing.

Everything works fine.

The way that it works is that if the URL is present, I set a localstorage item (`testing: true`) and if this is present in the local storage, my variable is then set to `true`, which means I am in testing mode.

However, in protractor, even after changing the base URL to include the params, the localstorage item doesn't get set and my app is not in testing mode.

what am I doing wrong here?

here's the config file:

```
exports.config = {
    specs: ['tests/e2e/*.js'],
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8100/?test=true",
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);

        var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
          displayStacktrace: false,
          displaySuccessful: true,
          displayFailed: true
        }));

        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        var junitReporter = new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('tests/e2e/');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    }
};
```

and the code that sets the localStorage item is the following:

```
<script>
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) {
                url = window.location.href;
            }
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        var isTesting = getParameterByName('test');

        if (isTesting === "true"){
            debugger
            localStorage.setItem('testing', true)
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('testing')
        }

        window.__TESTING__ = localStorage.getItem('testing');
        console.log (window.__TESTING__);
</script>
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly change the value of local storage from protractor using

```
browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem('testing',true)");
```

Add the above statement inside onPrepare method of protractor config file.